# Producer Consumer Program using wait() and notify() in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am doing classic Producer-Consumer problem in Java using low level synchronization and wait() and notify(). I know there are better implementations using structures from java.util.concurrent package but my problem revolves around low level implementation:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static Object obj = new Object();

    public static void producer() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (obj) {
            while (true) {
                if (list.size() == 10) {
                    System.out.println("Queue full.. Waiting to Add");
                    obj.wait();
                } else {
                    int value = new Random().nextInt(100);
                    if (value <= 10) {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                        System.out.println("The element added was : " + value);
                        list.add(value);
                        obj.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (obj) {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                if (list.size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Queue is empty...Waiting to remove");
                    obj.wait();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The element removed was : "
                            + list.remove(0));
                    obj.notify();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

There are 2 threads in the program, 1 each for producer and consumer specifically. The code works just fine.

**The only issue** is that producer goes on to produce messages until the maximum at once (until size is 10 for the list), and consumer consumes all 10 at once.

How can I make producer and consumer work at the same time?

This is the sample output:

```
The element added was : 4
The element added was : 0
The element added was : 0
The element added was : 4
The element added was : 3
The element added was : 1
The element added was : 10
The element added was : 10
The element added was : 3
The element added was : 9
Queue full.. Waiting to Add
The element removed was : 4
The element removed was : 0
The element removed was : 0
The element removed was : 4
The element removed was : 3
The element removed was : 1
The element removed was : 10
The element removed was : 10
The element removed was : 3
The element removed was : 9
Queue is empty...Waiting to remove
```

**Edit:** Here is the corrected code:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static Object obj = new Object();

    public static void producer() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            if (list.size() == 10) {
                System.out.println("Waiting to add");
                synchronized (obj) {
                    obj.wait();
                }
            }
            synchronized (obj) {
                int value = new Random().nextInt(10);
                list.add(value);
                System.out.println("Added to list: " + value);
                obj.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            if (list.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Waiting to remove");
                synchronized (obj) {
                    obj.wait();
                }
            }
            synchronized (obj) {
                int removed = list.remove(0);
                System.out.println("Removed from list: " + removed);
                obj.notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `if (list.size() == 10)`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis just to simulate maximum size/depth of the queue

Comment: Do you see how it applies to _The only issue is that producer goes on to produce messages until the maximum at once (until size is 10 for the list), and consumer consumes all 10 at once._?

Comment: Yes. The thread waits `(obj.wait())` if the maximum size of the list is reached. But after `obj.notify()`, it should continue again in the `while(true)` loop to produce

Comment: `notify()` does not release the lock of the corresponding object.

Comment: could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not run two thread in synchronized block with same object. When one method is running another method can not run until another thread call `wait` method.

To solve this problem you should just put `add` and `remove` in synchronized block. For more information see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Producer and Consumer problem is the classic example of multiple-process synchronization problem. This describes two process, producer and consumer which share the common resources, buffer. Producer job is to generate data and put it into a buffer and consumer job is consume the generated data and remove from the buffer.

Producer must ensure that no element should be added when buffer is full, it should call `wait()` until consumer consume some data  and `notify` to the producer thread AND consumer must ensure that it should not try to remove item from buffer when it is already empty, it should call `wait()` which simply waits until producer generate data and add it into buffer and notify to the consumer using `notify` or `notifyAll`.

This problem can be solved using `BlockingQueue` interface which do manage this producer and consumer implementation own.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project `Properties`.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author sakshi
 */
public class ThreadProducer {

    static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static class Producer implements Runnable {

        List<Integer> list;

        public Producer(List<Integer> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (list) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (list.size() >= 1) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("producer is waiting ");
                            list.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("produce=" + i);
                    list.add(i);
                    list.notifyAll();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

            //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable {

        List<Integer> list;

        public Consumer(List<Integer> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            synchronized (list) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                    while (list.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Consumer is waiting");
                        try {
                            list.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();;
                        }

                    }

                    int k = list.remove(0);
                    System.out.println("consume=" + k);
                    list.notifyAll();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(list));
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(list));
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();

    }
}
```

### Output:

```
produce=0
producer is waiting 
consume=0
Consumer is waiting
produce=1
producer is waiting 
consume=1
Consumer is waiting
produce=2
producer is waiting 
consume=2
Consumer is waiting
produce=3
producer is waiting 
consume=3
Consumer is waiting
produce=4
producer is waiting 
consume=4
Consumer is waiting
produce=5
producer is waiting 
consume=5
Consumer is waiting
produce=6
producer is waiting 
consume=6
Consumer is waiting
produce=7
producer is waiting 
consume=7
Consumer is waiting
produce=8
producer is waiting 
consume=8
Consumer is waiting
produce=9
consume=9
```

Comment: Good example. But it's better to use while loop on condition in Producer because of spurious wake up possibility.

Answer (score 0):

class Resources {

```
private final int capacity = 2;
public static int value = 0;

LinkedList < Integer > list;

Resources() {
    list = new LinkedList < > ();
}

void consume() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        synchronized(this) {
            while (list.size() == 0) {
                wait();
            }
            int val = list.removeFirst();
            System.out.println("Value consumed:" + val);
            notify();
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

void produce() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        synchronized(this) {
            while (list.size() == capacity) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println("Value produced:" + value);
            list.add(value++);
            notify();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        }
    }
}
```

}

class MyThread5 extends Thread {

```
Resources rs;
String name;

public String getNames() {
    return name;
}

public MyThread5(Resources rs, String name) {
    this.rs = rs;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (this.getNames().equals("Producer")) {
        try {
            this.rs.produce();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyThread5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            this.rs.consume();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyThread5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

public class ProducerConsumerExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Resources rs = new Resources();
        MyThread5 m1 = new MyThread5(rs, "Producer");
        MyThread5 m2 = new MyThread5(rs, "Consumer");
        m1.start();
        m2.start();

        m1.join();
        m2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProducerConsumerExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `list.size() == 10` , instead you can check `list.size == 1`.

For producer produced, one wait for the other one till consumer consumes. Refer this [Producer Consumer Problem - Solution using wait and notify In Java](http://adnjavainterview.blogspot.com/2017/08/producer-consumer-problem-solution.html)

Comment: Link is dead unfortunately.