# Not able to implement threads as required in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, thread-safety

I am having trouble implementing the below scenario as I am new to multithreading. Can anyone help me with this?

The requirement is as below:

**One thread created prime numbers from 1 to infinity. Another thread that writes those numbers to the console. Write code that runs these two threads.**

This is what I tried:

```
class func1 implements Runnable{



    public void run(){
    int x=1, counter=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=infinity; i++){
        if (isPrime(i)){
            p[counter] = i;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    }
}

class func2 implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
    int x=1, counter=0;
    int[] p=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=infinity; i++){
                System.out.println(“Prime number:”+p[i]);       

    }
    }
}
public class test{
 static volatile int[] arr;
public static void main(String[] args){
    func1 obj1 = new func1(arr);
    func2 obj2 = new func2(arr);
    thread t1, t2;
    t1 = new thread(obj1);
    t2 = new thread(obj2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to implement a producer/consumer pattern

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<=infinity; i++){` where is infinity defined?

Comment: infinity is just random . Please ignore

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of producer consumer pattern. Producer creates some integer values, populates them in a blocking queue and consumer pulls them from the queue.

Producer:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Producer implements Runnable{
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue){
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            queue.offer(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (queue.peek() != null) {
                Integer number = queue.poll();
                System.out.println("Integer is >>> " + number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);
        Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);

        producerThread.start();
        consumerThread.start();
    }
}
```

You can produce/consume primes. The logic inside run() method of Producer/Consumer will change. This can also be implemented using wait/notify.

Comment: can u implement this without using blocking queues?

Comment: producer/consumer can be implemented without using blocking queue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591043/producer-consumer-program-using-wait-and-notify-in-java

Comment: that's what I am looking for. Could you please answer here ?